# Не получается добавить mapstruct в проект Spring через maven

Tags: spring-mvc, maven, mapper

Я пытаюсь добавить mapstruct в мой Spring проект.

У меня есть сущность User. Мне нужно вывести список пользователей в панель администратора. Для это я сделал dto UserForAdmin, mapper UserMapper и rest контроллер AdminRestControlle. Когда я пытаюсь получить mapper UserMapper я получаю ошибки.

Я пытаюсь пойти двумя путями:

1. Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class)

Я получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for
>   ru.project.mapper.UserMapper

2. Через Autowired

Я получаю ошибку

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-07-17 15:47:07.886
>   ERROR 13652 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field userMapper in ru.project.controller.rest.AdminRestController
>   required a bean of type 'ru.project.mapper.UserMapper' that could not
>   be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'ru.project.mapper.UserMapper' in
>   your configuration.

Привожу свой исходный код

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>The project is project of resourse for investors.</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>                 
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Мой interface UserMapper:

```
package ru.project.mapper;

import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import ru.project.domain.User;
import ru.project.dto.UserForAdmin;

@Mapper
//@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    UserForAdmin UserToUserForAdmin(User user);

    List<UserForAdmin> UserListToUserForAdminList(List<User> user);


}
```

Мой rest контроллер:

```
package ru.project.controller.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ru.project.dto.UserForAdmin;
import ru.project.mapper.UserMapper;
import ru.project.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class AdminRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //@Autowired
    //private UserMapper userMapper;

    @GetMapping("/admin/users")
    public List<UserForAdmin> findAllUsers(){

        UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

        return userMapper.UserListToUserForAdminList(userService.findAll()); 
    }

}
```

Я бы хотел использовать Autowired. Предлагали как-то запустить maven (mvn package).Но у меня стоит Spring Tools Suite 4 maven я сам не ставил и как понимаю запуск maven за меня выполняет STS4 к тому же как я понял для генерации имплементации интерфейса производятся настройки m2e-apt плагина для Eclipse, а так же в pom добавляется плагин maven-compiler-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Упростил pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.8</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Собрал из командной строки

> mvn clean install

Должно сгенерироваться и скопилироваться UserMapperImpl
[image: см]

запустил

> java -jar target/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Работает и для:

> UserMapper userMapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

и для:

```
@Autowired
private UserMapper userMapper;
```

> @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")

Comment: В какой IDE вы это делали?

Comment: А автоматически класс сгенерировать не получится? Вроде пишут, что должно как-то автоматически генерироваться.

Comment: я использовал intellij idea community edition - думаю это не важно, потому что сборку я запускал с командной строки.

Comment: классы сгенерируются и скомпелироваться должгы на этапе compile шаге maven lifecycle https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html